# Can't create a database in Azure SQL using SQLAlchemy: "Cannot open database requested by the login"

Tags: sqlalchemy, azure-sql-database

For some reason, the following code that uses sql alchemy to create a database:

```
from sqlalchemy import Engine
from sqlalchemy_utils import create_database, database_exists    

engine: Engine = create_sync_db_engine()
    
if not database_exists(engine.url):
    create_database(engine.url)
```

Fails on `create_database` with

```
>       return self.loaded_dbapi.connect(*cargs, **cparams)
E       sqlalchemy.exc.ProgrammingError: (pyodbc.ProgrammingError) ('42000', '[42000] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Cannot open database "test" requested by the login. The login failed. (4060) (SQLDriverConnect)')
```

Even though,

- The same sqlalchemy code worked when I had a postgres backend.
- Connecting manually to the (master) database and creating a database using `create database db_name;` works;
- After I create a database manually, my sqlalchemy code is able to manipulate the database (with `engine`), so there are no issues with the connection string.

My conclusion is that it is a bug in SQLAlchemy with AzureSQL backend. Is it the case and is there a workaround other than using `exec(text(f'CREATE DATABASE test'))`?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use create_engine instead of create_sync_db_engine. For example:

```
import urllib
from sqlalchemy import create_engine,text
import pandas as pd

server   = 'servername.database.windows.net'
database = 'databasename'
username = 'username'
password = 'password!'   
driver   = '{ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server}'

conn = f"""Driver={driver};Server=tcp:{server},1433;Database={database};
Uid={username};Pwd={password};Encrypt=yes;TrustServerCertificate=no;Connection Timeout=30;"""

params = urllib.parse.quote_plus(conn)
conn_str = 'mssql+pyodbc:///?autocommit=true&odbc_connect={}'.format(params)
engine = create_engine(conn_str, echo=True)

query = 'SELECT @@version'

with engine.connect() as connection:
    df = pd.read_sql_query(sql=text(query), con=connection)
print(df.to_markdown())
```